# Cocoapods and fastlane issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods, fastlane

I'm working on a project where some new cocoapods dependencies just get introduced I need to install cocoa pods dependencies using pod install command.

So far if don't use **pod install** command Fastlane did create **.ipa** and upload it to the test flight portal.

but when I run **pod install** command cocoa change the **library search path** & **header_search_paths** and because of that there are other dependencies like  **tabby-ios-sdk** doesn't get installed which is needed to create the build.

> as you can see I can able to install the tabby-ios-sdk dependency whiteout running the pod install.

```
admin@Admins-MacBook-Pro Ama % xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace $workspace -scheme $scheme 
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace Ama.xcworkspace -scheme Ama

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Resolve Package Graph

Resolved source packages:
  Tabby: https://github.com/tabby-ai/tabby-ios-sdk @ main

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB3F7A05-2653-418B-9FDB-DC27C9D1C55D, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:28EEFA35-CC7D-4AB9-AB8B-B9E5CA6DE3C2, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5959D197-FD0F-4F6D-8183-9141BC41A634, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B310A0AF-A06C-45AF-B7A9-C9DD1878DAB9, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:BBD1C1D9-98F9-4452-B8BB-A31B38E6CC9A, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9D546563-5E6B-4A4B-97A8-95709E7F995D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:19D9A025-540C-4FCA-ACD8-E32FC2343D69, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D0CE35CE-0288-4A9D-9256-8FF79AF488CE, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B32B5126-A705-44B6-A5F0-2A98F3508DE2, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D8277E0E-B199-4D08-8FCB-4437240F6A2A, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:979BE269-07B1-4559-BB6A-FEDD00ABCF7F, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7DB9375C-7B8B-4C42-BAFA-3B92250FB362, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F5E16484-F561-487F-B866-BEEE23878119, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6012115A-5197-433B-A77F-D34B0A5098D0, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1154FD63-CE60-40DE-98A7-669A7815216E, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F3A55A42-1AD3-459B-AE0E-2266EA86EC31, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AD19457A-800E-4E82-B1C1-02C86B2DA7D6, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0D509309-86AC-4FC9-9D42-CE5DE84E0B3D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1F7600D9-E334-4031-9E7B-806818272DDB, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:96E5BED2-CE84-4B29-BF1B-EF38FC98E49F, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3FFAA71C-0B6E-4AA8-BCB2-1D5E638FD852, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0BBC8481-36D1-4369-B733-652FF56663EA, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:96AB3377-EEF7-49FA-B0F2-DC80BE315143, OS:14.5, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1A8D057C-8786-4B93-91D1-B65BC75AAA51, OS:15.2, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:23BB1822-83AB-46B7-BA9C-90D09E4160C7, OS:14.5, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:29C868CD-7773-439A-B38A-3F0568CCB5F7, OS:15.2, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:87C5134B-3AD0-4582-BC87-4698E425BD4E, OS:14.5, name:iPad (8th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B231005A-B0FC-4FE2-8EB7-1D06659019B9, OS:15.2, name:iPad (9th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:CE18281A-0013-4A40-AF4C-E9E3F0A3E89C, OS:14.5, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E31DF2B9-980E-4274-854D-20F14380C79B, OS:15.2, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:99D9F1EE-3A64-439D-8732-91101AE14967, OS:14.5, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:41B01E02-FE60-4FF3-A60E-4502C6ED7092, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C6CD749A-A006-4048-AE4A-8FDEDB9DBCA8, OS:14.5, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E9422632-7987-4898-9C43-3B97F5005FA4, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2E73B895-9838-401F-B0CB-338B9F6F24A8, OS:14.5, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D83EF77F-6B53-4EAB-B2DA-8F1C08D6AEC9, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7BE50AB3-0EAD-4884-AE13-9C0FB9D6E153, OS:15.2, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
resolved source packages: Tabby
```

**but**

> when I run **pod install** command  all the Dependencies get installed from cocoa pods but then again if I try to install swift package mangar Dependencies
> it doesn't get installed please check the below output.

```
admin@Admins-MacBook-Pro Ama % pod install 

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 34 dependencies from the Podfile and 58 total pods installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `13.0` on target `Ama` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] The `Ama [Debug]` target overrides the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Ama/Pods-Ama.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Ama [Release]` target overrides the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Ama/Pods-Ama.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
admin@Admins-MacBook-Pro Ama % xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace $workspace -scheme $scheme 
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace Ama.xcworkspace -scheme Ama

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB3F7A05-2653-418B-9FDB-DC27C9D1C55D, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:28EEFA35-CC7D-4AB9-AB8B-B9E5CA6DE3C2, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5959D197-FD0F-4F6D-8183-9141BC41A634, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B310A0AF-A06C-45AF-B7A9-C9DD1878DAB9, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:BBD1C1D9-98F9-4452-B8BB-A31B38E6CC9A, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9D546563-5E6B-4A4B-97A8-95709E7F995D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:19D9A025-540C-4FCA-ACD8-E32FC2343D69, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D0CE35CE-0288-4A9D-9256-8FF79AF488CE, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B32B5126-A705-44B6-A5F0-2A98F3508DE2, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D8277E0E-B199-4D08-8FCB-4437240F6A2A, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:979BE269-07B1-4559-BB6A-FEDD00ABCF7F, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7DB9375C-7B8B-4C42-BAFA-3B92250FB362, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F5E16484-F561-487F-B866-BEEE23878119, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6012115A-5197-433B-A77F-D34B0A5098D0, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1154FD63-CE60-40DE-98A7-669A7815216E, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F3A55A42-1AD3-459B-AE0E-2266EA86EC31, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AD19457A-800E-4E82-B1C1-02C86B2DA7D6, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0D509309-86AC-4FC9-9D42-CE5DE84E0B3D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1F7600D9-E334-4031-9E7B-806818272DDB, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:96E5BED2-CE84-4B29-BF1B-EF38FC98E49F, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3FFAA71C-0B6E-4AA8-BCB2-1D5E638FD852, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0BBC8481-36D1-4369-B733-652FF56663EA, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:96AB3377-EEF7-49FA-B0F2-DC80BE315143, OS:14.5, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1A8D057C-8786-4B93-91D1-B65BC75AAA51, OS:15.2, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:23BB1822-83AB-46B7-BA9C-90D09E4160C7, OS:14.5, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:29C868CD-7773-439A-B38A-3F0568CCB5F7, OS:15.2, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:87C5134B-3AD0-4582-BC87-4698E425BD4E, OS:14.5, name:iPad (8th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B231005A-B0FC-4FE2-8EB7-1D06659019B9, OS:15.2, name:iPad (9th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:CE18281A-0013-4A40-AF4C-E9E3F0A3E89C, OS:14.5, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E31DF2B9-980E-4274-854D-20F14380C79B, OS:15.2, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:99D9F1EE-3A64-439D-8732-91101AE14967, OS:14.5, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:41B01E02-FE60-4FF3-A60E-4502C6ED7092, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C6CD749A-A006-4048-AE4A-8FDEDB9DBCA8, OS:14.5, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E9422632-7987-4898-9C43-3B97F5005FA4, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2E73B895-9838-401F-B0CB-338B9F6F24A8, OS:14.5, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D83EF77F-6B53-4EAB-B2DA-8F1C08D6AEC9, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7BE50AB3-0EAD-4884-AE13-9C0FB9D6E153, OS:15.2, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
resolved source packages: 
admin@Admins-MacBook-Pro Ama %
```

if you compare both outputs you will see the difference between the logs and just because of this every build which I create through Fastlane get failed

now what I'm doing i use Xcode to make build and upload it to test_flight but after add the tabby-sdk-module manually through swift package mangar

any help will be really appreciated